# Visual Basic equivalent to QBasic's Draw statement

Tags: vb6, drawing, qbasic, quickbasic, gw-basic

Is there a Visual Basic (or even .NET or C++) equivalent to or implementation of GW-BASIC and QBasic's DRAW statement?

I have a very old program that outputs drawings as strings in the DRAW statement's format, and would like to render them in a Windows application I am developing in Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [VBTutor - Lesson 18: Graphics](http://www.vbtutor.net/vb6/lesson18.html)

In particular, you may need to use the Line method:

```
Line (0, 0)-(1000, 2000), VbRed 
' Draws a red line from 0,0 to 1000,2000
```

or the Circle method:

```
Circle (400, 400), 500, VbRed 
' draws red circle centered at (400, 400) with a radius of 500 twips
```

Comment: I was hoping more for a function that I can use as a drop in replacement for DRAW? The QuickBasic program reads a text file and sends the contents of the text file directly to the DRAW statement.